# Block / stop click on embed flash / swf

Tags: flash, embed, block

I have the fallowing  embed script

```
<embed src="http://flash-clocks.com/neon-flash-clock.swf?timeOffset=local&faceColor=0x000000&numbersColor=0xffffff&edgeColor=0xffffff&glowColor=0x000000&glowBlur=10&glowStrength=2&hourHandColor=0xffffff&minuteHandColor=0xffffff&secondHandColor=0xffffff" width=70px height=70px wmode="transparent" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
```

I have it shown on my page and i want to stop redirection when i click on it. Because it's sending me to their website.

Is there a way to stop it? I don't have any ideea in my mind and can't find something/ a way to stop that.

Comment: Try to add `AllowScriptAccess="never"` parameter  , like : `<embed allowscriptaccess="never" src="flash-clocks.com/.... `

Comment: I'd suggest to add `onclick="return false;"`, but the redirection might be triggered by the flash container. Besides, I'm not sure if you're allowed to do that, you better check their conditions first.